# Excel - How to Filter out Values Based on 2 fields

Tags: excel

Does anyone know how to filter out values based on two fields?

Basically, I have 3 columns, turbine ID, String ID, and Area.

I am wanting a formula that when I put in the Turbine ID (from column A),  it then looks at the string ID (in column b) and then filters all the values out which are in column B from Column A.

I.e

If I put `Turbine = 6`, it then filters out turbines `4,2` from the list.

```
|Turbine ID   | String ID   | Area |
 1              8,9          800m2
 6              4,2          600m2
```

I then want to summarie the Area_HA (i can do this part)

Here is a picture for better explanation:

[image: Image of spreadsheet]

Comment: When you type value that you want to filter String ID would you type the entire contents ( **Equals...**) of the cell, or would you want to use **Contains**?

Comment: Is my answer not acceptable? If answer brought you to a solution please check it.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer consider you have a cell the contains the desired turbine ID known as `[Turbine]` and you have a cell that contains the desired string ID known as `[String]`. Let's also consider that your data is in the range of `A1:C100` .
Let's say that you want **Contains...** for String ID then use.

```
=FILTER(A1:C100,(A1:A100=[Turbine])*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH([String],B1:B100))))
```

Let's say that you want **Equals...** with all other items as above then us:

```
=FILTER(A1:C100,(A1:A100=[Turbine])*(B1:B100=[String]))
```

[References](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function)